# initramfs prompt "mount: can't read etc/fstab" after grub rescue

Tags: grubrescue, initramfs

I had a bootable USB key witk ubuntustudio with two partitions:

1. `/dev/sdb1` with Ubuntu
2. and a fat32 `/dev/sdb2`.

Then I realized that Windows only reads partitions if they are the first. So I moved the partitions and now I have ubuntu on /dev/sdb2 and fat32 on /dev/sdb1. I made this creating an image of the old `/dev/sdb1` with ubuntu by `dd` command and then restoring it on the new `/dev/sdb2` with `dd` again.

So obviously now the USB pen fails to reboot and give me the grub rescue prompt
I made this, after having verified that the `vmlinuz` and `initrd` files are in (hd0,msdos2) partition:

```
grub rescue>  set root=(hd0,msdos2)/boot  
grub rescue>  insmod linux  
grub rescue>  linux (hd0,msdos2)/boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-17-lowlatency  
grub rescue>  initrd (hd0,msdos2)/boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-17-lowlatency  
grub rescue>  boot
```

When I boot I fall into initramfs prompt. I think that is because the `/dev/sdb2` is not mounted. Because after the boot command I get:

```
mount:can't read 'etc/fstab': No such file or directory  
Begin: Running /scripts/init-bottom ... mounting /dev on /root/dev failed: No such file or directory
```

But how can I tell to grub which is the new partition from inside grub rescue prompt?

Answer (score 0):

On `dev/sdb2` (your ubuntu partition) you need to edit and update `/etc/fstab`

You can do this by mounting the partition under Ubuntu and using gedit.

Update the root partition to point to the new partition.

You will then need to update grub.

Comment: The /etc/fstab on actual /dev/sdb2 is
    
    `UUID=23b36b1b-d937-4f07-8b8a-4f038ca12384 /        ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1  
    UUID=A4DA-D605  /windows        vfat    utf8,umask=007,gid=46 0       1  
    UUID=9648f4d6-55ac-457a-a241-9be725b5db96 none     swap    sw              0       0  `

and the UUID of /dev/sdb2 is unchanged; The output from blkid is

    `/dev/sdb2: UUID="23b36b1b-d937-4f07-8b8a-4f038ca12384" TYPE="ext4"  `

So what should I change?

Comment: fstab looks good, re-install grub https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair